# How to convert "4.791245e-1" to a number in python3

Tags: python-3.x, math

From an algorithm, I get the number **"4.791245e-1"** and I need to compare it to normal numbers like **.50**. How can I convert it to a normal number?

just comparing it doesn't work

```
if 4.791245e-1 >= 0.5:
```

...do something...

got an error from it

Comment: `float("4.791245e-1")`

Comment: what error do you get? In fact, your code that you say doesn't work (after 'just comparing it doesn't work'), works for me in both python2 and python3.

Comment: @swalladge: Agreed, that's perfectly legal code. Just ran `if 4.791245e-1 >= 0.5: pass` myself in both 2.7.15 and 3.7.1, no problems. The test returns `False` (because `4.791245e-1` is just `0.4791245`, and that's less than `0.5`), but it doesn't error.

Comment: `4.791245e-1` is a normal number. You've got to educate yourself about engineering notation.

Comment: ok, will try again.
>>> if 4.791245e-1 < 0.5:
...  print("something")
... 
something

Comment: @vbgaming so? `4.791245e-1` is less than `0.5`

Comment: Yes indeed, the e-1 means the number must be divided by 10 thus: 0.4791245 which is less than 0.5. You can read about [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)